# Can You Display 'Related Content' in a Task List?

Tags: workflow, document-library, task-list

I would like to be able to display the related content (i.e. from a document library) in a task list that is tied to a 2013 workflow.  Is this possible?

Comment: The related content column should be already available in workflow tasks list. Can you not find it?

Comment: No, I guess I can't...only 'Related Items' is available (which only displays the paperclip).  Related content isn't available as a site column to add to the task list either.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it's actually called "Related Items". So when you say "related content", do you mean the "See also" feature on the display form of any task in the tasks list?

Comment: When I modify the view in my task list, I can see a column for 'related content' that shows the document (for instance) that kicked off my workflow (and task list).  It disappears after that task, so I was looking at 'related item', but that only shows that there is '1 related item'.

Comment: I know about you are talking about now. The internal name of that field is **WorkflowLink** and it is one of the [builtin fields in SP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.workflowlink.aspx). I am however confused about what are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: Sorry, I have a document library where new documents kick off a workflow that assigns the tasks.  I just want the users, when they go out to their task list, to see both the task item as well as the document that they are supposed to be reviewing (without having to go to the document library).

Answer (score 2):

#### Let us clarify the question first

Tasks created in SharePoint 2013 from a workflow that uses the SharePoint 2013 workflow platform (not 2010) will not set the **Related Content** (aka [WorkflowLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.workflowlink.aspx)) field for the task in the associated workflow tasks list. I think only the **approval process/workflow** which uses the SharePoint 2010 workflow platform does this.

You want the user to be able to go to the workflow tasks list and view the tasks assigned to him, and for each task to have a link in the view that open the document for which the task was created.

#### Solutions

The easiest way is for the user to open a task in the display form and she/he will be able to view the task details plus a field called **Related Items** that offers a link to the document.

If you really want to show the link to the document in the workflow tasks list view(s), then you could modify the CSR (Client Side Rendering) of the view using JS and JSLink property of the view webpart. See an example on how to do this [here](http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2014/03/14/customize-related-items-field-in-sharepoint-2013/). 
Be aware that this solution works only for tasks created by workflows that use the SharePoint 2013 workflow platform (not 2010 platform). Also, if you have multiple views, you will have to modify the CSR for each view.